# Denormalized table. SQL Select

Tags: sql, db2

As I understand I have a denormalized table. Here is some list of table columns:

```
... C, F, T, C1, F1, T1, .... C8, T8, F8.....
```

Is it possible to select those values in a rows?
Something like this:

```
C, F, T
C1, F1, T1
......
C8, F8, T8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it easily with a `union all`:

```
select C, F, T from table t
union all
select C1, F1, T1 from table t
union all
. . .
select C8, F8, T8 from table t;
```

Note the use of `union all` instead of `union`.  `union` does automatic duplicate elimination, so you might not get all your values with `union` (as well as it being a more expensive operation).

This will generally result in the table being scanned 9 times.  If you have a large table, there are other methods that are likely to be more efficient.

EDIT:

A more efficient method is likely to be a `cross join` and `case`.  In DB2, I think this would be:

```
select (case n.n when 0 then C
                 when 1 then C1
                  . . .
                 when 8 then C8
        end) as C,
       (case n.n when 0 then F
                 when 1 then F1
                  . . .
                 when 8 then F8
        end) as F,
       (case n.n when 0 then T
                 when 1 then T1
                  . . .
                 when 8 then T8
        end) as T       
from table t cross join
     (select 0 as n from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1 union all . . .
      select 9 from sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) n;
```

This may seem like more work, but it should only be reading the bigger table once, with the rest of the work being in-memory operations.

Comment: as you say there are other methods that are likely to be more efficient. Could you please describe them too?

Comment: sql execution time is twice longer than doing a SELECT C, F, T, C1, F1, T1, .... C8, T8, F8

Answer (score 1):

```
select c,f,t from table
union all
select c1,f1,t1 from table
union all
select c8,f8,t8 from table
```

Make sure to filter by WHERE clause each SELECT statement.

Answer (score 0):

A trick similar to Gordons is to use `LATERAL` to avoid multiple scans:

```
with t(c1,t1,f1,c2,t2,f2) as ( values (1,2,3,4,5,6) ) 
select y.c, y.t, y.f 
from t x 
cross join lateral ( values (x.c1, x.t1, x.f1)
                          , (x.c2, x.t2, x.f2) ) y(c,t,f)

C           T           F          
----------- ----------- -----------
          1           2           3
          4           5           6
```